# Interacting with global react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an app in react and want to make a sidebar that comes out when I click various links across the app. So I have started by making a wrapper component and just putting the sidebar and page stuff underneath that,

```
SetupRailsPage = React.createClass

  render: ->
    div id: 'setup-rails-page',

      Sidebar()

      div className: 'container',
        div className: 'row',
          div className: 'col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2',
            RailsBox(rails: @props.rails)
```

This feels inefficient though and I'd ideally like to not have to add it to every single page like that. I haven't seen any react code regarding this and wanted to know what the 'react way' is to handle something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect [ReactRouter](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) could help here.

If you can decompose your application into :

- a 'common part' (that would contain the SideBar, and maybe other stuff), and
- a different component for each 'logical' page ;

Then that's what react-router [claims](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/overview.md) to solve.

EDIT : the OP really wanted to have a "global" event notification system, to avoid passing many callbacks, as described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html).

Comment: I have used react router and react router component, but even with those how would I interact with the common sidebar? I would still have to pass a ton of callbacks down to the item being clicked to trigger the opening of the sidebar, right?

Comment: That's hard to say without seeing the code where the sidebar and the "item being clicked" interact. Now, maybe your "inner" components can call a simple "onClicked" callback, and a component that is a parent of both those inner components and the sidebar will handle interaction. But yes, in general, if you want to communicate with a 'parent' component, either you'll have to use callbacks (or channels, or something to communicate...), or use a "global" event bus if that's the simplest (https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html)

Comment: Right now I have it setup so it is passing callbacks up. It works, but then I'll have toggleSidebar methods all over my app. Like I need to pass that method from the page down to a list wrapper, then to the list, then to the item being clicked. This seems a little excessive. I also need it to be able to pass different stuff into that sidebar, which I think is a seperate issue but a soultion that did all of that feels missing in react right now. Even the "global" event system you showed doesn't deal with this scenario. Maybe just expose a function to window for this special case?

Comment: Yes, for the "global" event system, I meant adding an "event bus" to window, and, as the article explains in the end, subscribe to this instead. If you really need global, just use global, nobody's watching ;)

Comment: Great thanks. I'm just somewhat new to more involved JS and global functions are new to me. I wish they'd just put an example in there. They also need a better feedback and revision system for their docs on that note.

Comment: Great I'm using the global event system now! I had another question though, how can I insert a react component dynamically into another react component. I can't use renderComponent like normal because things are already mounted.

Comment: Note sure I know what you mean.. can you just inspect the props / state to know which component must be displayed ? The most "dynamic" thing I can think of would be passing the component's constructor function as a prop, and calling this function in render... (that's what I understand react-router does)

Comment: Interesting, I was thinking something along those lines. I'll check out the react router source code to try that out. I would just use react router, but I need the sidebar to display multiple components on each page.

Comment: Ok so I am planning on adding a string that has the name of the desired component. You said pass the constructor function, and I'm a little fuzzy on what that is exactly (sorry, js newb). Would that be ReactComponent or ReactComponent()? Because I thought those only give you the description of the component, not something that can be rendered.

Comment: No, I meant passing the *function* as a props. React.createClass returns a *function* to create components ; in JS, you can pass functions around and you can call them dynamically. See this : http://jsfiddle.net/ema3xpzk/2/ (I'll gladly expand on this if you ask another, more focussed question ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the Flux pattern ( http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html). Your application state is handled by data stores and you change this state by creating actions. Any change to a store causes it to emit a 'changed' event, causing interested components to re-render. Your sidebar would generate actions,causing changes to stores, in turn causing the relevant parts of your app to update. Fluxxor (http://fluxxor.com/) is a very useful plugin to help with this pattern.